# Visual Studio 2019 closing curly brace not under the opening brace (it's fully left aligned instead)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting, visual-studio-2019, curly-braces

Recently the closing curly brace start to align on the fully left instead of under the opening brace, but only when the braces are empties :

(I'm in Visual Studio 2019, in C# code)
Steps :

write this :

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    class myClass
    { }
}
```

Then hit return while in between the class braces, it did this :

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    class myClass
    { 
 }
}
```

Note the class closing brace not being under the opening one.

How can I have this instead, where is the formatting option ?

```
namespace myNameSpace
{
    class myClass
    { 
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I tried in VS2019 and cannot reproduce your problem. I get the desired alignment of braces. (With or without a semicolon after the inner closing brace!)

Comment: Hey Robin.  I apologize for the people who downvote you and marked the question as "should be closed" without giving you an explanation. That's uncalled for. I think this is a very legit question. I voted you back up and provided what I hope is a helpful answer.

Comment: Ctrl E+D will format the whole doc.

Comment: @Adrian...Same here...cant reproduce it with 2019.

Comment: It is working with CTRL+..., but it was working as is (on return) some time ago.  I know it may not be reproducable for most of you (since it wasn't for me too a few weeks ago), but I'm looking for someone whoe did have the same issues or that know how to resolve this.  Thanks.

Comment: @Robin Are you using any Extensions?

Comment: @ChrisCatignani, yes, but I just disabled them all and so far the problem is still there, but I will investigate more on this one.

Comment: You may need to do a little reading to get to the bottom of it...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-formatting-conventions?view=vs-2019#c-formatting-settings

Here is a way to customize the .editorconfig

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks, See my response below, I found some maybe explanation and workarround....

Answer (score 5):

Indentation and bracing styles tend to be religious issues.  When you move from team to team, you end up having to learn the local brace/indent style.  There's a whole Wikipedia article on it (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).

In Visual Studio, you can setup your preferred brace/indent style.  My guess is that your bracing/indentation is busted and needs to be reset.

To get there:

```
Tools ->> Options ->> Text Editor ->> C# ->> Code Style ->> Formatting ->> Indentation
```

Once you are there, if thing are the way you want them, change them to something else before OK-ing out of the dialog.  Then do it again and change it back.  If they don't match your desired style, just change things (the idea being - you need to make a change so that your change gets saved).

Good luck

Comment: Good advice...the key is to just make a change and then change it back.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen this happen before in various versions of VS.  It's not really reproducible, but sometimes for no explainable reason, VS just starts acting this way.

There are a couple of ways to handle this.  The quick fix is to just hit

```
ctrl+k+d
```

And that will auto-align all of the code (and comments) on the open file.  While that will fix the misaligned brackets after the fact, it won't stop VS from still doing it.

If it gets too annoying (which it can!) then what you can do is a `ctrl+a` to copy everything.  Then paste it into a text file (so you don't accidentally lose it). Remove the file from the project. Then, delete the actual file from the working folder. Close and re-open VS. Then re-create the file and paste all of the contents back into it.

That *should* solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like one of those *special* features that makes VS such a wonderful IDE!

Comment: @Adrian Yes, exactly! I don't see it very often, but when it pops up, it's incredibly vexing. I go through the steps I outlined above while cursing under my breath.

Comment: And Stack Overflow is as good a place as any to find a quick fix (thus saving on a lot of self-harm and hair-pulling). Don't get the attitude of some folks here who like to vote down and/or close such questions. Quite tribal, sometimes?

Comment: @Adrian, agreed. The number of spiteful users on here who get off on downvoting people is sad. This is supposed to be a "let's help each other!" community.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston..Sometimes its warranted...but when its you getting the downvotes...man it smarts. I got banned for 9 months for asking questions. I almost grit my teeth when I need an answer now

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Sometimes the downvotes *are* warranted. But my personal opinion is that a downvote should ALWAYS be accompanied by an explanation. In fact, I wish SO would make that required. But they hardly ever are. Drive-by shooters read a question and for some unknown reason they don't like it, and it's far too easy to just click the down arrow and move on. It's rude.

Comment: Thanks all, as a matter of fact, ctrl+k+d work, but removing file isn't and it's doing this in all files and in all (c#) projects. which lead me to think it may be a formatting option ?

Comment: @RobinLeblond... now that, I confess, I have never seen. That is really weird. I can't imagine there being such a formatting option, but I've seen stranger things in VS.  You might try closing VS and deleting all of the `bin` and `obj` folders in the solution. They will re-generate on the next build. It sounds like something got corrupted.

Comment: @Flydog57 may have the answer for you. I didn't know about that.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston I did try this, doesn't work eiher, but good point. Also try many options on and off (as Flydog57 suggested) and so far it still didn't work.  And I confirm, it's really anoying, as I have to hit ctrl+k+d all the time...

Comment: @RobinLeblond Ah man, I feel for you. Sadly, I am out of idea.  I've run into stuff like this with VS before where I just ended up literally uninstalling VS and re-installing it, which wastes an entire day. (In my case, I became unable to see the value of any variables or objects while in debug mode.)  If you happen to figure this one out, I hope you'll come back here and let us know what the solution is.

Comment: See my response below, I found some maybe explanation and workarround....

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it’s appeared, but I might be wrong, that the smart tab management had changed lately and that now it is no longer inserting tab at the beggining of a second empty line in a bloc (like some other code editor).  Therefor leaving only a space on the second line, leading to my “problem”.

I always used **smart tab indenting** for all languagse and then lately it seen to have changed then causing this.  **So the solution** for me was to go back to **Block Indenting** and it work well.  I don’t know what other differences that may cause, but...

NOTE: That this **only occur if using the Keep tabs** option

Thanks all, your comments lead me to a solution (or at least a work-around).

Answer (score 2):

Auto-formatting as you type looks to be turned off by default in Visual Studio 2019.  To auto-format your code, go to **Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting** and select the option *Automatically format when typing* then select your preferences as to when auto-format should be triggered.  Example screenshot:

[Auto-format option in Visual Studio 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlT6W.png)